# How to implement twitter login for a website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I have searched so far and I'm not able to find the right solution for implementing twitter login for website. 
Would be helpful if I get any suggestions or tutorials link about how to implement it using javascript.

Comment: I prefer PHP but codebird is available in both js and PHP flavours, I use codebird for most everything Twitter related.

Answer (score 0):

A number of resources and JavaScript libraries available.  A good start is [Twitter Signin Resources](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries)